# Access variables inside foreach and if loop from outside

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am stuck with my code so I cam here to find some help.
The story is like this: I have a foreach loop with some if/else conditions inside it. Each if returns some values that i wanna use external, for queries in different sql tables, etc. But I do not know how to get these variables to work outside. Basically I want the variables that are printed with echo to be used outside the if conditionals.Thanks in advance !

```
foreach ($result as $a) {
    $current++;

    if (!empty($cautare)){

        //Daca nu are pret redus ia pretul intreg
       if (empty($pret[1])) { 

       $pretintreg=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $pret[0]->innertext);
       $cautalira =  array('/£/', '/From/');
       $scoatelira = array('', '');
       $nouintreg = preg_replace($cautalira, $scoatelira , $pretintreg);
       echo '<br /> Produsul cu modelul ' . $a['model'] . ' este pe stoc si are pretul ' . $nouintreg.'<br />';

       } else {

       //Daca are pret redus il scoate
       $pretintreg=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $pret[1]->innertext);
       $pretredus=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $pret[0]->innertext);

       $cautalira =  array('/£/', '/From/');
       $scoatelira = array('', '');

       $nouintreg = preg_replace($cautalira, $scoatelira , $pretintreg);
       $nouredus = preg_replace($cautalira, $scoatelira , $pretredus);

       echo '<br /> Produsul cu modelul ' . $a['model'] . ' este pe stoc si are pretul intreg ' . $nouintreg. ' si pretul redus ' . $nouredus . '<br />';



       }
    }

    outputProgress($current, count($result));

}
```

Comment: please don't use irrelevent tags. I removed mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use var outside the foreach.

Two ways :

- you put your use inside the foreach, instead of you echo
- you use an array created before the loop, that you'll feed inside and use after

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Well I want to use another conditions instead of echo, but I already have an if/else statement there so I am confused. I actually need to query the $nouredus variable into another table and if it exists to compare and update the value.

Comment: @AdrianZ. `if(test1){statement1;} else if(test2){statement2;}/*could add other else if here*/else {else statement;}` this ?

Comment: I am aware of this but I am afraid it will not work in my case as I wanna condition a variable created during one of the conditions above. So  I think I should feed an array, right?

Comment: @AdrianZ. I don't get what you want, could you edit your question / simplify it and maybe add what you want in algorithm

Comment: Inside my ELSE statement I have a variable called $nouintreg. I want this variable compared with a value from a sql table so automatically I need another IF statement. But the variable is created inside the condition.

Comment: @AdrianZ. you can put your if inside no ? just after you set your new var